# How is "user" defined for the rate limit?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I've been reading through Google's documentation about the per user rate limit and I'm trying to ensure I understand how this works.  Based off what I've been able to find, it looks like unless the userIp or quotaUser values are set in the OAuth token, google will use the IP address that the request comes from to apply the user based per second rate limit.  Could someone confirm whether or not this is true?  I couldn't find anything explicitly stating this for the GoogleDrive API, but I was able to locate this for several other of Google's APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct by default Google users the IP that is sending the request. For calculating user rate limit.

If I run a script on a server all the requests will be coming from the server.  If I send quotaUser=somerandomvalue  then each request will come from a different user.